# Fill placeholders in runtime when running a function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, function, boto3

I am working on a python script to print an IAM Policy after running a function, I have written my function in such a way that the placeholders are filled as soon as we run the function and the placeholders for "start_time" and"end_time" are filled during runtime.This is my function:

```
import json
import meta_templates
from jinja2 import Template
start_time_1 = input("What's the start time")
end_time1 = input("What's the end time")
def create_aws_iam_policy_template(**kwargs):
  template_data = {}
  template_data["region"] = kwargs.get('region')
  template_data["start_time"] = kwargs.get('end_time')
  template_data["end_time"] = kwargs.get('start_time')
  template_data["instance_types"] = kwargs.get('instance_type')
  template_data["ebs_volume_size"] = kwargs.get('ebs_volume_size')
  template_data["meta_template_name"] = kwargs.get('meta_template_name')

  meta_template_dict = getattr(meta_templates, template_data["meta_template_name"])
  meta_template_json = json.dumps(meta_template_dict)
  template_json = Template(meta_template_json).render(template_data)

  template_json = create_aws_iam_policy_template(
  region="us-east-2",
  instance_type="t2.micro",
  ebs_volume_size="20",
  meta_template_name="ec2_policy_meta_template",
  start_time = "start_time_1",
  end_time = "end_time1"
)
print(template_json)
```

This my IAM policy template:

```
ec2_policy_meta_template = { 
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::instance/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::network-interface/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::key-pair/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::security-group/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::subnet/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::volume/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::image/ami-*"
                ],
                "Condition": {
                    "ForAllValues:NumericLessThanEquals": {
                        "ec2:VolumeSize": "{{ebs_volume_size}}"
                    },
                    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                        "ec2:InstanceType": "{{instance_type}}"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                    "ec2:StartInstances",
                    "ec2:StopInstances"
                ],
                "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::instance/*",
                "Condition": {
                    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                        "ec2:InstanceType": "{{instance_type}}"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:Describe*",
                    "ec2:GetConsole*",
                    "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                    "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
                    "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                    "ec2:DescribeKeyPairs",
                    "ec2:CreateKeyPair"
                ],
                "Resource": "*",
                "Condition": {
                    "DateGreaterThan": {
                        "aws:CurrentTime": "{{start_time}}"
                    },
                    "DateLessThanEquals": {
                        "aws:CurrentTime": "{{end_time}}"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

How do I fill the placeholders for "start_time" and "end_time"

Comment: What's your question/issue?

Comment: I have updated the question with the issue I am facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are **missing commas** in your `template_json = create_aws_iam_policy_template`. It should be:

```
template_json = create_aws_iam_policy_template(
  region="us-east-2",
  instance_type="t2.micro",
  ebs_volume_size="20",
  meta_template_name="ec2_policy_meta_template",
  start_time = "start_time_1",
  end_time = "end_time1"
)
```

Update:

You are also **mising return** in your `create_aws_iam_policy_template` so it will always return `null`.

```
    return template_json
```

Comment: The error is still there even after the comma

Comment: @PranaySinghParihar You are still missing commas. Please use all commans as shown in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, yeah right, I missed it I have corrected it now but after running it I am still not able to fill the placeholder in the template

Comment: @PranaySinghParihar What ever is happening its not due to the error you reported (`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`). My answer addressed the error posted. I don't know what's causing your new issue.

Comment: Any tips on how should I be trying to fill the placeholders from runtime of the function

Comment: @PranaySinghParihar I updated the answer. Anyway, if this and my previous answers to your past questions were helpful, their acceptance would be appreciated.